# Images are not showing in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using magento 1.9. I have upgraded hostmonster server and before upgrading the website was working fine. After upgrading the server now images are not showing on frontend and backend. 
I have tried a lot and searched the solution but unable to resolve the issue.
Any guidance or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: what kind of upgrade you had done so far; does the Os changed?. if so the image path may also be changed... make sure u have correct permission. for the folders..

check this by uploading new image for a product

Comment: If the images aren't loading on the front or backend, the browser will kick a console error as the images will have a 404 (not found). If you open up the console (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/) and inspect whatever errors might be there, you can update your question with that, it will make it easier to track down the "why".

Answer (score 0):

I'd verify that the images moved over in your upgrade.

So for example, if you had an image in this folder: http://www.awesomedomain.com/images/product1image.jpg

... go to the new site and make sure that the images transferred over.

I'd also check folder and file permissions to make sure that they have read access (i.e. 644) permissions so that they can be downloaded in a browser.

If any of the physical paths changed, this could also be an issue.

I hope this helps...

Comment: I did all the things but my problem was resolved by just removing .htaccess file from medial folder.

Comment: But thank you so much for your effort